# What is the best practice for logistic regression data perspective?

Tags: logistic, data-transformation, sigmoid-curve

I'm running into an interesting problem (for me at least) right now where I'm worried that my data setup is negatively influencing the accuracy of my model.

Lets use historical chess matches as our frame of reference.

Currently my dataset is based on the projected winner. It looks something like this:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|} 
\text{GameID} &\text{ProjectedWinningPlayer} & \text{ELOProbForProjectedWinner}& \text{Result} \\ \hline
\text{1} & \text{Kasparov} & \text{51} & \text{lose} \\ \hline
\text{2} & \text{Fischer} & \text{59} & \text{win} \\ \hline
\text{3} & \text{Carlsen} & \text{58} & \text{win} \\ \hline
\text{...} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

The potential problem, I think is that since everything is based on the projected winner there are no values below 0.50. So when I go to fit a logistic regression, because there are no reference points below 0.50 the solver can basically do whatever it wants to the tail of the sigmoid function and that freedom could cause it to overfit the early portions of the graph.

Would it be better practice to spread out the observations more? Instead of setting up the data from the perspective of the favorite I can set it up from the perspective of whoever makes the first move. In that case the above example might look this this:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|} 
\text{GameID} &\text{FirstMovePlayer} & \text{ELOProbForFirstMovePlayer}& \text{Result} \\ \hline
\text{1} & \text{Morphy} & \text{49} & \text{win} \\ \hline
\text{2} & \text{Fischer} & \text{59} & \text{win} \\ \hline
\text{3} & \text{Anand} & \text{42} & \text{lose} \\ \hline
\text{...} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Which would give some observations below 0.50 to help constrain the sigmoid function.

Whats the best practice here? I think I've talked myself into the more neutral perspective. It would at least negate the need for stratified kfolds.

Comment: Have you considered including both, winner and looser? I think that is what Bradley-Terry models do in a similar but slightly different setting. I am not a mathematician but if no better answer comes up soon you might want to look that up.